# A path between two points

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, path-connected

Say we have a set $S\subset\Bbb{R^n}$, and $p\in\text{int}(S), q\in\text{int}(\Bbb{R^n}\setminus S)$. I have to prove that every path between $p,q$ goes through $\partial S$ (the boundary of S).
So I let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb{R^n}$ be a continuous path s.t $\gamma(0)=p, \gamma(1)=q$, and I want to prove that there exists $c\in [0,1]$ s.t $\gamma(c)\in\partial S$.

My attempt was assuming by contradiction that such $c$ doesn't exist and reach a contradiction, but I don't know how to even start. Intuitively, this statement makes sense but I don't know how to prove it.

I did notice that $\gamma ([0,1])$ is compact, though I don't know if it helps. I want to show that if there doesn't exists such $c$, then $\gamma([0,1])\subseteq\text{int}(S)$ or $\gamma([0,1])\subseteq\text{int}(\Bbb{R^n}\setminus S)$.

Comment: Let $\alpha = \sup\{t: \gamma(t)\in S\}$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: compactness isn't that important, connectedness of $[0,1]$ *is*.

Comment: Can $\gamma(\alpha)$ be in the interior of $S$ or the interior of the complement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every set $S$ we have that $$\Bbb R^n = \rm{int}(S) \cup \partial S \cup \rm{int}(\Bbb R^n \setminus S)$$

where the union is (pairwise) disjoint. $p$ is in the leftmost set, $q$ in the rightmost. So *if* $\gamma[[0,1]] \cap \partial S = \emptyset$, we could write

$$\gamma[[0,1]]  = \left((\gamma[[0,1]] ) \cap \rm{int}(S)\right) \cup \left((\gamma[[0,1]] ) \cap \rm{int}(\Bbb R^n \setminus S)\right)$$

which makes the connected set $\gamma[[0,1]]$ a disjoint union of two non-empty ($p$ and $q$ are witness to that) and disjoint relatively open sets, contradiction.

So the intersection with $\partial S$ is *not* empty.

Comment: I know that $[0,1]$ is not connected, does that mean its image under a continuous function is also path - connected?

Comment: @GalBenAyun $[0,1]$ *is* connected and trivially path-connected, as is its image under the continuous $\gamma$. Why do you ask?

Comment: My question is - is it generally true that if $S$ is path connected and $f$ continuous then $f(S)$ is path connected?

Comment: @GalBenAyun . If $S$ is path-connected and $f$ is continuous: For $p,q\in f(S)$ let $u,v\in S$ with $p=f(u)$ and $q=f(v)$. Then let $g:[0,1]\to S$ be continuous with $g(0)=u$ and $g(1)=v$. A composition of continuous functions is continuous, so $(fg):[0,1]\to f(S)$ is continuous with $(fg)(0)=p$ and $(fg)(1)=q.$

Comment: @GalBenAyun Yes, as Daniel showed. But what I use is just that $X$ connected, $f$ continuous, then $f[X]$ connected, applied to $X=[0,1]$.